# Batch Rename Double Letter Folder Problems

Tags: batch-file, rename, file-rename

Ok so I'm super close to doing what I need to do.

I'm having an issue with my rename command and a double letter at the end of the folder. The folder names in the code have been changed for privacy, Spaces have been kept to show how the folders would be named.
The double letter is uppercase I (eye), this can't be changed.
Yes this file exists.

Example:
FolderII - error: The system cannot find the path specified.
Folder - Works
FolderI - works

```
for /r "C:\Folder Name" %%a in (*) do if "%%~nxa"=="FileFound" set p=%%~dpnxa
for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims=." %%A in ("%p%") do set Build=%%B
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%G in ('wmic os get localdatetime /value') do set datetime=%%G
for /f "tokens=3 delims=\" %%Z in ("%p%") do set filepath=%%Z
set year=%datetime:~0,4%
set month=%datetime:~4,2%
set day=%datetime:~6,2%

set dbname=Logdb%year%.%Build%

REN "C:\Folder Name\%filepath%\%dbname%" "Logdb%month%-%day%-%year%.%Build%"
```

**OUTPUT**

**EDITED!**
CMD>REN "C:\Folder Name\FolderII\Logdb2020.ext" "Logdb11-23-2020.ext"
The system cannot find the file specified.
**Added**
CMD>REN "C:\Folder Name\Folder\Logdb2020.ext" "Logdb11-23-2020.ext"
**THIS works**

*******EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION********
I'll explain this how I intended it to work, which it does as long as the folder it's being assigned to doesn't have a II in it.

**1st line:** Search this particular folder for a file called "SYSCON" no extension, once found assign to p the file path of the file for 2nd line
**2nd line:**Open file found at 1st line and get the extension of the file listed inside the file and assign it to Build
**3rd line:**Get the current date to assign to the new file name in REN
**4th line:**Use the file path found in line 1 to get the folder name for the REN
**5-7** set date variables
**Line 8:**Assign the new file name to variable
**Line 9:**Rename the old file at the location found to the new file name generated

I'm not a batch developer, I've literally written these lines as they work for me, but I'm always willing to learn how to do better, I'm a PHP programmer. This is a different project. 
The folder structure is fluid for the application. The reason for the search for the initial file is to find the file in 1 of 4 folders and then get that actual folder name. 
I can echo all the variables and see the correct file path, the correct file name and the correct new file name.
When it comes to rename the file in the folder with II, it fails to find the actual file to do the rename on, that's where I'm stuck.

IMAGE of Output echoed as it steps through the lines, for privacy sake I have to change the file names. Here's the CMD output for, I hope, better understanding

[image: CMD output (censored)]

Comment: You'll need to be more forthcoming with the actual names of the files/directories involved. Sadly the code posted would only set `p` to the last full-filename that matched "name=FileFound" and `dbname` would be set to `Logdb2020.ext` if your reported `year` and `build` are as shown. The `rename` command generated would thus be `REN "C:\Folder Name\FolderII\Logdb2020.ext" "Logdb11-23-2020.ext"`, not as you report.

Comment: @Magoo, you are correct. I have made the updates and a brief explaination of how I see the script working. My issue is with the folder name FolderII not working but Folder working in the REN part.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive, based upon your lack of specific information, but as a best guess, I'd assume that something like this should perform the task, I think your example is trying to achieve.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Tokens=1-3 Delims=/ " %%G In (
    '""%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" \: . /NJH /L | "%__AppDir__%find.exe" " 123""'
) Do Set "YYYY=%%G" & Set "MM=%%H" & Set "DD=%%I"

For /D %%G In (C:\Folder Name\*) Do For %%H In ("%%G\SYSCON"
) Do If "%%~aH" Lss "d" If "%%~aH" GEq "-" (
    For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1,* Delims=." %%I In ("%%H") Do Set "Build=%%J"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Ren "%%G\Logdb%YYYY%.!Build!" "Logdb%MM%-%DD%-%YYYY%.!Build!"
    EndLocal)
```

The example above expects the the string you're using for the `Build` variable is on the last non empty line of the target file, *(ASCII text with CRLF line endings)*. If it is the only non empty line in that target file, then perhaps the following would be more useful:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Tokens=1-3 Delims=/ " %%G In (
    '""%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" \: . /NJH /L | "%__AppDir__%find.exe" " 123""'
) Do Set "YYYY=%%G" & Set "MM=%%H" & Set "DD=%%I"

For /D %%G In (C:\Folder Name\*) Do For %%H In ("%%G\SYSCON"
) Do If "%%~aH" Lss "d" If "%%~aH" GEq "-" (
    For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1,* Delims=." %%I In ("%%H"
    ) Do Ren "%%G\Logdb%YYYY%.%%J" "Logdb%MM%-%DD%-%YYYY%.%%J")
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the data assigned to `build` contains trailing spaces and perhaps some invisible characters. The easy way would be to simply change `1*` to `1,2`.

Since <kbd>Space</kbd> is a default delimiter, `%%B` will be assigned the value between the first and second spaces on the line. Tough if you want spaces in the extension, but do you really want to use extensions with spaces?

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty; in which case `var` becomes *undefined*) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned.